# XNA Adding a Texture2D to Main Constructor

Tags: c#, xna

I have a class named Ball (for pong project) and I need to pass the Texture2D through the Main Constructor as so:

Ball.cs

```
 public class Ball
    {
        Texture2D _ballSprite;
        private float _ballSpeed;
        private Vector2 _ballMovement;
        private Vector2 _ballPosition;

        private const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
        private const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;


        public Ball(Texture2D sprite) 
        {
            _ballSprite = sprite;

        }
```

and then in the Main
 Game1.cs

```
 Ball ball = new Ball();
```

What should I pass though the parameters in Main to have the Texture2D appear?

Comment: Are you asking *how* to pass a texture instance to the `Ball` constructor, or *what* to pass?

Comment: technically both. I know I need to pass the Texture2D because when I highlight the error is shows Texture2D sprite, however, I am not sure what I need to place in the parameter. I try to put _ballSprite but it does not exist in Game1.cs and I want it to

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't pass `Texture2D` in constructor. Graphic resources like `Texture2D` can become disposed while game is running in event of graphic device being reset. And you will need a new instances of all `Texture2D` objects each time that happens.

Therefore in XNA all content loading of graphical resources should be done inside `LoadContent()` method. Your `Game` class overrides `LoadContent()` method. There you can load your texture like this: `byBall.BallSprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("balltexture");` (you need to make `BallSprite` property public in that case)

Or you could create a method for loading inside Ball class

```
public void LoadContent(Content content)
{
   _ballSprite = content.Load<Texture2D>("balltexture");
}
```

and then call `myBall.LoadContent(Content)` from overriden `Game` class `LoadContent()` method.

Note that that `Content` object is `ContentManager` and will in case you load same texture multiple times, load that texture in memory only once (first time load is called). For all subsequent calls same `Texture2D` instance will be returned.

`Game.LoadContent()` method is called by XNA before first update and each time graphic device is reset (that can happen for number of reasons at any time). So you need to be careful what you do inside `LoadContent()` method. If you would for instance try to create `Ball` class instance inside `LoadContent()`, that ball instance could be replaced by new ball instance at any time mid game and `_ballSpeed`, `_ballMovement`, `_ballPosition` values would be lost.